# Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header

Tags: arduino, esp8266, blink

I'm trying to program ESP8266 Node MCU v0.9 using Arduino IDE. I'm trying to upload the most common sketch i.e. **blink** which is available in the examples of ESP8266. Even then I'm getting this error -

```
    Arduino: 1.8.11 (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 0.9 (ESP-12 Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Legacy (new can return nullptr), All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, All Flash Contents, 115200"

    Executable segment sizes:


    IROM   : 227612          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR) 


    IRAM   : 26776   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (ICACHE_RAM_ATTR, ISRs...) 


    DATA   : 1252  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


    RODATA : 672   ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


    BSS    : 24880 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


    Sketch uses 256312 bytes (24%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
    Global variables use 26804 bytes (32%) of dynamic memory, leaving 55116 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
    esptool.py v2.8
    Serial port COM13
    Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____.....____Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Tejashree\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3/tools/upload.py", line 65, in <module>
        esptool.main(cmdline)
      File "C:/Users/Tejashree/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.3/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2890, in main
        esp.connect(args.before)
      File "C:/Users/Tejashree/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.3/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 483, in connect
        raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))
    esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header


    This report would have more information with
    "Show verbose output during compilation"
    option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I Checked the COM port, drivers and libraries needed. Everything looks just fine. I don't understand where it is going wrong. How to get rid of this error?

Comment: A few possibilities: Wrong COM port selected. The device may not be in Flash mode (some NodeMCU models require you to press and hold the Flash button when starting the upload). Maybe the USB to Serial adapter driver was not installed correctly. Maybe you’re using a charge-only USB cable. Does the device actually make a connect sound on your PC when plugging it in?

Comment: @StarCat COM port was correct. I checked that. Device was in flash mode. I did not try pressing Flash button. I'll try that. But driver is also installed correctly. I can hear connect sound after plugging in and I can see it in device manager under COM. The cable I'm using is not charge-only.

Comment: Have you gotten any further yet? You can try [manually putting the device into flash mode](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/flash/#putting-device-into-flash-mode) but that should not really be necessary. Are you sure you have a NodeMCU v0.9? If you bought it recently it's likely a v1.0. Otherwise it looks like your code compiles just fine.

Comment: Look at this :  _"This report would have more information with   "Show verbose output during compilation"    option enabled in File -> Preferences"_, Go there and enable this option in order to get an more detailed error message.

Comment: @StarCat I tried to connect the uC with a new cable. At first, the code got uploaded. But when I tried to upload another code, it gave me the same error as above. I tried again a few more times, but it is giving me the same error. And once again I changed the cable, the same thing happened. It uploaded the code at first and then failed to upload in the next attempts. And yes, It is v0.9 only.

Comment: @mguima I'll get the more details as per your suggestion.

Comment: When testing the issue on 2 different computers running the exact same Arduino software, I've found that the upload process works on 1 system and no longer works on the other system. If the upload process works on one system and no longer works on the other system. The question is, what is different between the two systems, obviously something changed.